# IO Error:Cannot open image while generating barcode after freezing using py2exe

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, barcode, py2exe, ioerror

I have used pyBarcode library to generate Barcode in my software and its works perfectly fine while I load it from command line but once I freeze the entire software using py2exe I am getting IO error while generating the barcode.

```
File "panels.pyc", line 383, in generate
File "barcodeGenerator.pyc", line 9, in generate
File "barcode\base.pyc", line 68, in save
File "barcode\codex.pyc", line 251, in render
File "barcode\base.pyc", line 103, in render
File "barcode\writer.pyc", line 188, in render
File "barcode\writer.pyc", line 280, in _paint_text
File "PIL\ImageFont.pyc", line 248, in truetype
File "PIL\ImageFont.pyc", line 146, in __init__
IOError: cannot open resource
```

Here panels.py is my python script from where I call generate method of barcodeGenerator.py whose code is given below.

barcodeGenerator.py :-

```
import barcode
from barcode import generate
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from PIL import PngImagePlugin

def generate(details,path):
  EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
  ean = EAN(details, writer=ImageWriter())
  barcodePic = ean.save(path + 'barcode')
```

And yes the setup.py file using which is freeze is:-

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

includes = ["HuffmanDictionary"]

setup(
options = {
            "py2exe": {"includes": includes}
          },
console=['MainFrame.py',"extraModules.py","encode.py","decode.py","panels.py","barcodeGenerator.py" ]
)
```

Please could some one point the error I made.I am very close to completing the entire software this is the last bug and I am using windows 7 64 bit.

EDIT: Already have been to this [link](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/PILAndFontfiles) and tried but still not working for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally after digging deep into google and asking question on the mailing lists of py2exe I realized that there was some error in py2exe it just didn't include the some modules without any reason. So I added the entire module in the folder of .exe as include_package and that worked as a charm. Also cx_Freeze is a good alternative to using py2exe since it is easy to use and is supported on multiple platform.

Hope this helps other who are wasting time searching on internet.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on your py2exe solution? I have the same issue, and I've included the entire barcode module in my configuration file but I continue to receive this error. What does your py2exe config look like?

Answer (score 3):

I found this in *[your python installation directory]*\Lib\site-packages\barcode\writer.py

```
PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
FONT = os.path.join(PATH, 'DejaVuSansMono.ttf')
```

DejaVuSansMono.ttf is also in the same directory.
But, after cx_freeze built, barcode writer give an invalid font path to ImageFont.

My workaround is to copy DejaVuSansMono.ttf to `Windows\Fonts` OS folder on the PC that will run your built executable.

Similar issue at [How I can load a font file with PIL.ImageFont.truetype without specifying the absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085996/how-i-can-load-a-font-file-with-pil-imagefont-truetype-without-specifying-the-ab)

Another workaround is to modify barcode\writer.py

```
#FONT = os.path.join(PATH, 'DejaVuSansMono.ttf')
FONT = 'arial.ttf'
```

I think arial.ttf should be in every `Windows\Fonts` (default font path) directory.

Comment: also make sure to include PIL in the py2exe packages option

Comment: This answer helps. I think this problem happens because pyinstaller does not package the 'DejaVuSansMono.ttf'  font file that the barcode library uses, so when the exe tries to use this font, the problem comes up.

Answer (score 0):

same problem :/, but the source code changed a bit.

in

```
C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\*your_project*\Lib\site-packages\barcode\writer.py
```

I changed

```
#PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
PATH = 'C:\Windows'
```

and

```
#self.font_path = os.path.join(PATH, "fonts", "DejaVuSansMono.ttf")
self.font_path = os.path.join(PATH, "fonts", "Arial.ttf")
```

sure this is not the best solution, but for this moment it helps me.