# How I can load a font file with PIL.ImageFont.truetype without specifying the absolute path?

Tags: python, ubuntu, fonts, python-imaging-library

When I write the code in Windows, this code can load the font file just fine:

```
ImageFont.truetype(filename='msyhbd.ttf', size=30);
```

I guess the font location is registered in Windows registry.
But when I move the code to Ubuntu, and copy the font file over to /usr/share/fonts/, the code cannot locate the font:

```
 self.font = core.getfont(font, size, index, encoding)
 IOError: cannot open resource
```

How can I get PIL to find the ttf file without specifying the absolute path?

Comment: If the font is TrueType (.ttf), did you put it in the TrueType subdirectory in /usr/share/fonts/? I would try now but I don't have access to a Ubuntu machine at the moment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the PIL documentation, only Windows font directory is searched:

> On Windows, if the given file name does not exist, the loader also looks in Windows fonts directory.

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefont.htm

So you need to write your own code to search for the full path on Linux.

However, Pillow, the PIL fork, currently has a PR to search a Linux directory. It's not exactly clear yet which directories to search for all Linux variants, but you can see the code here and perhaps contribute to the PR:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/682

Comment: It looks like this was fixed in https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/1054 so Linux and MacOS search for the font without the absolute path.

Comment: For Windows OS - Install fonts in windows font directory. Your python code will start working.

Answer (score 54):

To me worked this on xubuntu:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont

# sample text and font
unicode_text = u"Hello World!"
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMono.ttf", 28, encoding="unic")

# get the line size
text_width, text_height = font.getsize(unicode_text)

# create a blank canvas with extra space between lines
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (text_width + 10, text_height + 10), "orange")

# draw the text onto the text canvas, and use blue as the text color
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
draw.text((5,5), u'Hello World!', 'blue', font)

# save the blank canvas to a file
canvas.save("unicode-text.png", "PNG")
canvas.show()
```

[image]

## Windows version

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

unicode_text = u"Hello World!"
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 28, encoding="unic")
text_width, text_height = font.getsize(unicode_text)
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (text_width + 10, text_height + 10), "orange")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
draw.text((5, 5), u'Hello World!', 'blue', font)
canvas.save("unicode-text.png", "PNG")
canvas.show()
```

The output is the same as above:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is a [Python fontconfig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python-fontconfig) package, whereby one can access system font configuration,  The code posted by Jeeg_robot can be changed like so:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont
import fontconfig

# find a font file
fonts = fontconfig.query(lang='en')
for i in range(1, len(fonts)):
    if fonts[i].fontformat == 'TrueType':
        absolute_path = fonts[i].file
        break

# the rest is like the original code:
# sample text and font
unicode_text = u"Hello World!"
font = ImageFont.truetype(absolute_path, 28, encoding="unic")

# get the line size
text_width, text_height = font.getsize(unicode_text)

# create a blank canvas with extra space between lines
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (text_width + 10, text_height + 10), "orange")

# draw the text onto the text canvas, and use black as the text color
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
draw.text((5,5), u'Hello World!', 'blue', font)

# save the blank canvas to a file
canvas.save("unicode-text.png", "PNG")
canvas.show()
```

Comment: This package doesn't work on more modern versions of Python 3. I tested your example with 3.10 and it sadly doesn't work anymore. This is definitely not a bad answer. But I wanted to leave this info in case someone is getting stuck.

Answer (score 4):

On mac, I simply copy the font file Arial.ttf to the project directory and everything works.

Comment: Bad idea. Do you have rights to distribute that font?  Should every application make copies of all the system fonts it uses?

Comment: Yeah, make NFT for that font and sell it

Answer (score 1):

On Mac I had some fonts in the project dependencies

```
$ find . -name *.ttf*
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/shared/ubuntu.ttf
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/fonts/Vera.ttf
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/fonts/VeraBI.ttf
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/fonts/VeraBd.ttf
./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/fonts/VeraIt.ttf
```

so I passed in Vera like so

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(r'./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/reportlab/fonts/Vera.ttf', 50)
```

you can also get a font like this but the size was too small

```
font = ImageFont.load_default()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 while using Visual code, i had to do as below to make it work.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'] + "/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/Dance Floor.ttf", 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Debian, this allows you to load a .ttf or .otf font from the same directory as your Python script without having to specify the path:

```
custom_font = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'NameOfFont.ttf'))
```