# Python Pillow OSError: invalid argument for ImageFont.truetype method

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am getting OSError: invalid argument. I checked the documentation. It seems my argument is correct.

Pillow=9.5.0
Pythong=3.10

Here is my code:

```
draw.font = ImageFont.truetype(
                    'C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf',
                    32,
                    10,
                    layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_BASIC,
                )
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

Could you help me with this? Thank you

Comment: There's a superfluous comma before closing parenthesis `,)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can load a font file with PIL.ImageFont.truetype without specifying the absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085996/how-i-can-load-a-font-file-with-pil-imagefont-truetype-without-specifying-the-ab)

Comment: removing comma still have the same error ',)'

Comment: not sure absolute path works

Comment: Try `ImageFont.truetype('C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf', 32, layout_engine=ImageFont.Layout.BASIC)` instead.

Comment: it worked! But why can't I change index?

Comment: I don't know. Why do you want to change it?