# File converted to exe can't generate barcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, barcode

I tried to generate barcode and made a GUI using pyqt5 when I run it through scripts it works perfectly but when I converted the .py file to .exe file when I try to generate it, it gives many tracebacks

```
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import shutil
import os


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(607, 503)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-170, 220, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 180, 311, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.testEan(self.lineEdit.text()))
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Generate"))

    def testEan(self, i):
        EAN = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
        s = '0' * (8 - len(str(i)) - 1) + str(i)
        ean = EAN(s, writer=ImageWriter())
        fullname = ean.save(str(i))
        try:
            os.mkdir("Barcode")
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
        try:
            shutil.move(fullname, "Barcode")
        except:
            pass
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox().about(QtWidgets.QWidget(), "Info", "Success")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> NOTE : I have imported `pkg_resources.py2_warn` because without it
> when i try to execute the application it throws no module name
> `pkg_resources.py2_warn`

```
Traceback: (most recent call last)
 File "Bar.py" line 37, in <lambda>
 File "Bar.py" line 51, in testEan
 File "site packages\barcode\base.py" line 68 in save
 File "site packages\barcode\codex.py" line 261 in render
 File "site packages\barcode\base.py" line 111 in render
 File "site packages\barcode\writer.py" line 226 in render
 File "site packages\barcode\writer.py" line 356 in _paint_text
 File "site packages\PIL\ImageFont.py" line 648 in truetype
 File "site packages\PIL\ImageFont.py" line 645 in freetype
 File "site packages\PIL\ImageFont.py" line 193 in __init__
OsError : cannot open resource
```

```
OS          : windows 10
Python      : 3.8.3
Pyinstaller : 3.6
```

Is there any way to overcome that traceback error?

Answer (score 0):

[IO Error:Cannot open image while generating barcode after freezing using py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620179/io-errorcannot-open-image-while-generating-barcode-after-freezing-using-py2exe)

as stated here you should alter or include the font in you code, so it can read it.
I chosed to alter the code to a "standard" font instead.

i posted in a similar issue on the repo as well: https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/issues/69

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)