# After turning a python file into a .exe file the barcode module stops working

Tags: python, pyinstaller, barcode

After turning a python file into a .exe file the barcode module is no longer able to save an image file of a barcode.

for example this:

```
from barcode import Code39
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

myImage = Code39("0007", writer=ImageWriter(), add_checksum=False)
myImage.save("myImage.png")
```

Will work as a .py file but no longer as a .exe file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IO Error:Cannot open image while generating barcode after freezing using py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620179/io-errorcannot-open-image-while-generating-barcode-after-freezing-using-py2exe)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite strange and it is mentioned in [IO Error:Cannot open image while generating barcode after freezing using py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620179/io-errorcannot-open-image-while-generating-barcode-after-freezing-using-py2exe) but what you need to change has changed a tad bit so felt I could make this thread to help any beginners not knowing how to fix this.

The solution is to change this line of code:

```
self.font_path = os.path.join(PATH, "fonts", "DejaVuSansMono.ttf")
```

In the file writer.py in C:\Users\TERMINTATOR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\barcode .

To this:

```
self.font_path = 'arial.ttf'
```